# C static variables initialization

Tags: c, static

I learned some C and came across an explanation for static variables.
They showed this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fun()
{
  static int count = 0;
  count++;
  return count;
}
  
int main()
{
  printf("%d ", fun());
  printf("%d ", fun());
  return 0;
}
```

I can't understand why calling the function twice is fine, because the line

```
static int count = 0;
```

actually runs twice...
I can't understand how is that possible...
Can you actually declare it twice or does the compiler just ignore it the second time?

Comment: Static variable initialization only happens the first time the function is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (statics/globals) is where an initializing definition is *really* different from an uninitialized definition followed by an assignment.
Historically, the former even used to have different syntax (`int count /*no '=' here*/ 0;`).

When you do:

```
int fun() {
  static int count = 0;
  //...
}
```

then except for the different scopes (but not lifetimes) of `count`, it's equivalent to:

```
static int count = 0; //wider scope, same lifetime
int fun() {
  
  //...
}
```

In both cases, the static variable becomes initialized at load time, typically en-masse with other statics and globals in the executable.

Answer (score 1):

`static` variables are initialized on program startup, not every time the function is called.

Comment: C 2018 5.1.2 1 says “**All** objects with static storage duration shall be *initialized* (set to their initial values) **before** program startup”, emphasis added.

Comment: This answer is only half-correct. Please update it or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

> ... because the line `static int count = 0;` actually runs twice.

No.  Just once, right before `main()` is called.